# Mysqli php array index

Tags: php

```
$row = $overview_response->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
```

returns the following as an array:

```
Array ( [0] => 12 [1] => username [2] => email [3] => a53ccb24bfb1135eb45e675464f948 [4] => Test message [5] => 1 [6] => Test subject [7] => 2016-01-29 15:35:02 )
```

How could i access the parameters like only the username?

Been testing the following before:

```
foreach ($row as $key) {
    echo $key[1];
}
```

Comment: Use fetch_assoc to get a more manageable array, then you should be able to do $array[ 'username' ];

Comment: echo $row[1];      ??

Comment: @BlakeA.Nichols Got it :)

Comment: @devpro It's an array of items so i have to run it inside a foreach

Comment: as u mentioned what u have tested, is it not working?? any error?

Comment: note that if you only want the username, don't do a `select *`. it's a waste of resources fetching fields you're only going to throw away. `select username from ...` is far more efficient, and makes it explicitly clear what you want.

Comment: `$username = $row[1];` would be enough to get the username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$row` is an array so you can walk through the values using `foreach()`.
However the values of your array are not arrays.

so this command `echo $key[1]` is invalid as it tries to access the first element of `$key` but `$key` is a string.

You can get to your values by using something like:

```
$id = $row[0];
$username = $row[1];
// and so on
```

Comment: Now i only have one problem left, i thought row would contain each mysql element. How could i run the command for each returned array index of each array value?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/8b73cf32838546bb8f4752b68c37fab4 Theres only 1 element but 8 elements. and the foreach runs for each value actually.

Comment: My answer covers the "How could i access the parameters" part of your question, why it didn't work the way you tried it. Not getting the correct query result is another question.

Comment: take a look here for multiple rows http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
$row = $overview_response->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
```

returns to you an array. You can access key in array by it's index. I suppose `username` is value with key 1.

```
$row = $overview_response->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
var_dump($row[1]);
```

This is the simpliest way.

Other way can be using `MYSQLI_ASSOC` constant, which will return string keys instead of numeric keys:

```
$row = $overview_response->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
var_dump($row);
// after that you can still access username by key, 
// but now it will be the name of a corresponding field
var_dump($row['username']);   // if field is called `username`
```